# how to get list of document in a collection, using angular firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I a m trying to get the list of documents in collections, but m not getting any document,
This is code what i m trying-
`

```js
    schoolProductCollectionFetch(schoolName){
    
       const school = this.db.collection(schoolName)
       this.school$ = school.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(schoollist=>schoollist.map(s=>{
         const data = s.payload.doc.id;
         console.log(data);
         return data;
       })));
       return this.school$
     
      }
```

Database Format:
SchoolCollection->Documents->ProductCollection

```
SchoolCollection:{
   1st:{products:{}},
   2nd:{products:{}},
}
```

Have tried to represent the data format as in firestore, I want to get 1st, 2nd which are document id's for SchoolCollection,
Schema Snap:

[image: Schema Screenshot]
Note: Please let me know if more details needed to understand the query

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you still need this but you may want to try `collectionGroup('Name of collection')`.

Code should look like something similar to this:

```js
    this.afs.collectionGroup('Users')
      .valueChanges().subscribe(users => {
      
      //this.userNames is an "Any" before my constructor.
      this.userNames = users

      //for loop allows me to get all the document's data
      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        
        //these const allow me to play with If conditionals
        const userEmail = this.userNames[i].email;
        const userRole = this.userNames[i].role;

        if (userRole == "User") {
          continue;
        } else {
          console.log(userEmail);
        }
      }
    });
```

HTH in anything...

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```js
schoolProductCollectionFetch(): Observable<School[]> {
  return this.db
    .collection('schoolName')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map((snaps) =>
        snaps.map((snap) => {
          return new School({
            id: snap.payload.doc.id,
            ...(snap.payload.doc.data() as {}),
          });
        }),
      ),
      first(),
    );
}
```

After you get the data and create an instance of it, you can refactor this code, to make it more readable. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First question I have: You are passing in a parameter 'schoolName' into the function then doing `this.db.collection(schoolName)`. Now, is school name actually the name of the collection, or is it the ID of a document in the collection?

What error are you getting in your console output when you try this? Have you set up your firestore permissions to allow requests?

The database schema you posted is confusing, maybe an actual screen shot of your set up from the firebase console could be of more use.

***EDIT***

To get data for a collection using the firestore you have to build the correct path to the collection you want. In your example, doing something like `this.db.collection(schoolName).get()` will get all the documents in that collection. Note: *THIS WILL NOT GET ANY SUB COLLECTIONS!* This type of querying is not supported by Firebase at the time of writing this.

Let's say you want to get all the documents of the sub collection 'kitProducts'. This could be achieved by doing `this.db.collection(schoolName + "/1st/kitProducts").get()`. This returns all the documents in the sub collection 'kitProducts' that reside under a document with id '1st' in the schoolName collection. You must build these paths up in order to query them.

You seem to be working the realm of a real-time listeners on the collection. If this is your intention, you should use the `onSnapshot()` function. Taking the earlier example, writing something like `this.db.collection(schoolName + "/1st/kitProducts").onSnapshot()`. In this case, an event will be emitted any time a document within the kitProducts sub collection is edited, deleted, or added.

More reading:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: schoolName parameter includes the name of the collection, I m not getting any error in console or while running the method, neither m getting any output on this, will modify the question with schema screenshot

Comment: updated question with schema snap, Hope this detailing will add some input for solution finding

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this is not making that much help, I have already gone through this links, but somehow while implementing i m not getting values, if you can share working piece of code, that will be more helpful